# SQL INSERT INTO SUBFROM from QUERY in ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a receipt form where i want to receive payments from customer and knock off the invoices

I have created the Table Of Receipt Master

Field are , TID (Auto Number), Cutomer ID , Chq No, Amount, Bank, RVDate

Another Form Rvdetails:

ID (AutoNumber), Receipt ID (Join with TID of Receipt Master) SINVOICE ID, INvoice No, Totalinvamt, Customer ID, Bal, Amount

I want to insert RV Query Which has follwing data in to Rvdetail subform when select the customer which i afterupdate vba on Customer ID

```
Private Sub Cust_AfterUpdate()
Me.Refresh
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO rvdetails ( [Sinvoice ID],[Invoice No],TotalInvamt,Bal,Amount, [Customer ID]) SELECT RVquery.[Sinvoice ID],RVquery.[Invoice No], RVquery.Totalinvamt, RVquery.bal,0, Rvquery.[customer id]" & Me.[Customer ID] & " from [RVquery] where [RVquery].[Customer ID] = " & Me.Cust
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

attached images of RV Query & Form Design

the problem is that the when selecting the customer the rvquery filed not inserting in the subform

RVQUERY fileds are

SINVOICE ID , INVOICE NO, CUSTOMER ID, TOTALINVAMT, SUMOFAMOUNT, BAL

Please tell me where i m mistaking

Comment: Now the problem has been solved changed the Rvdetails reciept id filed in to TID and then correct the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Cust_AfterUpdate()
Me.Refresh
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO rvdetails ([Sinvoice ID],[Invoice No],TotalInvamt,Bal,[Customer ID], TID) SELECT rvquery.[Sinvoice ID],rvquery.[Invoice No],rvquery.totalinvamt, rvquery.bal, rvquery.[customer id]," & Me.TID & " from [rvquery] where [rvquery].[Customer ID] = " & Me.Cust
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Now the problem has been solved changed the Rvdetails reciept id field in to TID and then correct the code the corrected code is mention above